# Changing x-axis tick labels ggplot2 not working, making axis disappear, scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the x-axis tick labels in ggplot but I can't get it to work for some reason. I have the following code and plot:

```
ggplot(over36mo, aes(x=raceeth,y=pt,fill=factor(year.2cat))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=pt+se, ymin=pt-se), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 0.26, 0.02), limits=c(0,0.26)) +
labels=c("NHW","NHB","NHNA/PI","NHA","H")) +
  theme(axis.line.x=element_line(color="black"),
        axis.line.y=element_line(color="black"),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank()) +
xlab("All ages") + ylab("")
```

[image]

But when I try to change 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to different labels with `scale_x_discrete`, the x-axis disappears like so:

```
ggplot(over36mo, aes(x=raceeth,y=pt,fill=factor(year.2cat))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=pt+se, ymin=pt-se), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 0.26, 0.02), limits=c(0,0.26)) +
labels=c("NHW","NHB","NHNA/PI","NHA","H")) +
  theme(axis.line.x=element_line(color="black"),
    axis.line.y=element_line(color="black"),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    plot.background=element_blank()) +
xlab("All ages") + ylab("") +
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5"), labels=c("NHW","NHB","NHNA/PI","NHA","H")) +
```

[image]

It's probably obvious what's wrong but I can't figure it out. Here's a dput of my data if someone wants to give it a shot!

```
over36mo <- data.frame(
  z.surv.mos = rep(36, 10L),
  raceeth = rep(seq(1, 5, by = 1), each = 2L),
  year.2cat = rep(c(1, 2), 5),
  pt = c(
    0.10896243930756, 0.12919986395988, 0.10763696166101, 0.0918969557367,
    0.14186152615109, 0.12701814940611, 0.05405405405405, 0.09393141727008,
    0.08880901672474, 0.11716939090588
  ),
  nevent = c(9, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  ncensor = c(0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  nrisk = c(311, 96, 33, 9, 72, 21, 2, 2, 48, 20),
  cum.ev = c(2474, 2469, 287, 342, 440, 496, 35, 40, 505, 616),
  cum.cen = c(1, 958, 4, 107, 12, 198, 0, 13, 19, 239),
  pointflg = rep(1, 10L),
  pe = c(
    0.89103756069243, 0.87080013604011, 0.89236303833898, 0.90810304426329,
    0.8581384738489, 0.87298185059388, 0.94594594594594, 0.90606858272991,
    0.91119098327525, 0.88283060909411
  ),
  se = c(
    0.00591553159512, 0.00860912091676, 0.01746946721576, 0.01975702415208,
    0.01550071018085, 0.01904081251339, 0.03717461110299, 0.05797150600236,
    0.01228353765126, 0.01608823714602
  ),
  lower.cl = c(
    0.09796374785164, 0.11338170396883, 0.07830897003442, 0.06029765195198,
    0.11451353670001, 0.09468155080317, 0.01404207131432, 0.02802051731609,
    0.06772108402588, 0.08952365586359
  ),
  upper.cl = c(
    0.12119598770184, 0.14722485430136, 0.14794876641234, 0.1400560419898,
    0.17574073058836, 0.17039866945242, 0.20807761862723, 0.31488038035974,
    0.11646360310182, 0.15335238527538
  ),
  row.names = c("38", "134", "183", "246", "289", "366", "412", "452", "491", "563")
)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's because you are setting a discrete `x` scale but your `x` values are numeric. If you want to treat them as discrete, convert to a factor. Just change the first part to

```
ggplot(over36mo, aes(x=factor(raceeth), y=pt, fill=factor(year.2cat)))
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: SO SIMPLE. I figured it had something to do with that but didn't know how to change it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I have a scenario where the x-axis variable needs to be numeric, but the x-axis tick marks need to be text/character strings. Is there a way to achieve this?